# How to mock the view model with Hilt for unit testing fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I've got an android app setup for dependency injection using Hilt, and would like to unit test my fragments.

I'm currently creating my view model using:

```
private val viewModel: ExampleViewModel by viewModels()
```

And I am creating the fragment for testing using the code from [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-hilt/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/HiltExt.kt#L38)

I need to replace this ExampleViewModel with a mock, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will paste here the "danysantiago" response in a issue (https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1972) related to your question:

> Hilt ViewModel extension works by declaring modules that bind assisted
> factories to a map and not by binding concrete ViewModels. Therefore,
> what you want to do is bind the assisted factory of the concrete
> ViewModel using the key of the abstract ViewModel so that when
> HiltViewModelFactory looks up the factory based on class key it uses
> the assisted factory for the concrete ViewModel. This is suuuper
> obscure and hence why I mean not 'easily' available.
>
> However, if you can expand on the test case your are trying to write
> that could help us provide some guidance, I'm not sure if you are
> trying to mock/fake the ViewModel itself for tests, but Hilt testing
> APIs should allow you to replace dependencies in the ViewModel so you
> can write a test with the Fragment and the ViewModel.